# Can repetier host be connected to Ender 6 3D printer?

Tags: repetier-host, creality-ender-6

If so, please guide me through the process. I want to modify the G-Code to calibrate the extruder. I suspect my extruder is over extruding.

Comment: What have you tried/not tried? What kind of computer are you running, Mac or PC? You looking for a very broad answer; more information from you will help to give you more specific information.

Comment: Repetier host is not required here unless your run Repetier firmware (why on earth would you?).
The EEPROM on your printer board is likely locked down.
Use pronterface to connect to your printer, calibrate your e-steps via the M92 g-code there and add the result to your start g-code in your slicer.

Alternatively, install a proper version of Marlin to your board, so you can save the new steps/mm via the M500 command.

Comment: How to connect Repetier is described in [this answer](/a/10574). Also look into "[How do I calibrate the extruder of my printer?](/q/6483)". Note that you do not have to send the G-code through a console, you can also store these in a .gcode file and print the file.

Comment: @Oscar, I would give it a try. Would any stepper motor steps alteration I end up making in the .gcode in case of over extrusion (that I suspect is the case) be saved by default by the printer or do I have to update the firmware? I can share which version of Merlin I have on my printer.

Comment: @Beenum That depends on the board and the current firmware, e.g. the board needs to be able to save changes (e.g. SKR boards need an SD card for storing changes) and `M500` must be enabled for storing changes.